# Oracle Invalid Identifier

Tags: oracle

```
Error report:
ORA-00904: "RDD"."USED_END_DATE": invalid identifier
ORA-02063: preceding line from ADSWEBPROD
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

The following query is throwing me invalid an identifier error.

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE demo_date_array_type IS TABLE OF dc_demo_dates.demo_date_id%TYPE;
  updated_demo_dates demo_date_array_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT ddd.demo_date_id 
  BULK COLLECT INTO
    updated_demo_dates
  FROM 
    dc_demo_dates ddd 
  JOIN 
    dc_demo_reservations ddr 
  ON 
    ddd.reservation_id = ddr.reservation_id
    AND ddr.status NOT IN ('DENIED','CANCELLED')
    AND ddr.demo_type <> 'Training'
    AND ddr.environment IS NOT NULL
    AND ddd.last_update_date > SYSTIMESTAMP - 1           -- updated in the last day
    AND ddd.demo_start_date > SYSTIMESTAMP - 14 -- no older than 2 weeks
  JOIN
    (SELECT demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date 
     FROM rps_by_demo_date 
     GROUP BY demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date ) rdd
    ON rdd.demo_date_id = ddd.demo_date_id
  WHERE
    ddd.demo_start_date != NVL(rdd.used_start_date, SYSTIMESTAMP)  -- either start date
    OR ddd.demo_end_date != NVL(rdd.used_end_date, SYSTIMESTAMP);  -- or end date has changed
END;
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date` or If I change the last `OR` for an `AND`, the code executes successfully (except it doesn't give me the results I need)

Do you know what might be going on?
Thank you

EDIT:
I moved the group by clause from the subquery into the main query and obtained the results I wanted. But I still don't understand what was causing the error.

Comment: remove only the `, used_end_date` from the `group by`

Comment: If I remove the `, used_end_date` from the `group by` I cannot use it in the `select`; if I remove it from the `select` I cannot use it in the `where`.

Comment: sounds like you have duplicate rows of `demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date` (with the same values) - maybe you should try to pull only `DISTINCT` values ?

Comment: Your last `EDIT` section is very weird: how can you group by three fields when you only select one field ???

Comment: You were right about my last edit, it makes no difference to group by the other 2 columns if they are not in the select. About the `DISTINCT` I would expect the group by would be enough to bring me distinct rows of `demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date` does it not?

Answer (score 1):

try this :-

```
DECLARE
  TYPE demo_date_array_type IS TABLE OF dc_demo_dates.demo_date_id%TYPE;
  updated_demo_dates demo_date_array_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT ddd.demo_date_id 
  BULK COLLECT INTO
    updated_demo_dates
  FROM 
    dc_demo_dates ddd 
  JOIN 
    dc_demo_reservations ddr 
  ON 
    ddd.reservation_id = ddr.reservation_id
    AND ddr.status NOT IN ('DENIED','CANCELLED')
    AND ddr.demo_type <> 'Training'
    AND ddr.environment IS NOT NULL
    AND ddd.last_update_date > SYSTIMESTAMP - 1           -- updated in the last day
    AND ddd.demo_start_date > SYSTIMESTAMP - 14 -- no older than 2 weeks
  JOIN
    (SELECT demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date 
     FROM rps_by_demo_date 
     GROUP BY demo_date_id, used_start_date, used_end_date ) rdd
    ON rdd.demo_date_id = ddd.demo_date_id
    AND (ddd.demo_start_date != NVL(rdd.used_start_date, SYSTIMESTAMP)  
    OR ddd.demo_end_date != NVL(rdd.used_end_date, SYSTIMESTAMP));  
END;
```

I have moved the where clause to a join condition. Using a where clause with join operations sometimes lead to unexpected results. It might be possible that your where clause is not recognizing rdd. However, your join condition might recognize it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it and I'm still getting the same error
`ORA-00904: "RDD"."USED_END_DATE": invalid identifier
ORA-02063: preceding line from ADSWEBPROD
ORA-06512: at line 5`

Comment: Also, just as with the first query, if I change the OR for an AND it runs without any errors :/